# Get TreeNode "Created date" from Kentico 8 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I'm using Kentico 8 API.

I have a custom class in CMS that inherits from `TreeNode`.
I haven't found any way to get "Created date" for item of this class. Could you suggest any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the DocumentCreatedWhen field in the CMS_Documents table.  You can see this field if you take a look at the CMS_Tree_Joined view as well.

If you are extending the Treenode you should be able to access this property by TreeNode.DocumentCreatedWhen.  If you are not seeing it that way, try getting the value using TreeNode.GetValue("DocumentCreatedWhen")

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to use GetValue method. It just works